# Emacs: `cal-tex-cursor-month-landscape` is texing as portrait

Tags: latex, calendar

Emacs has a buit-in library to generate a landscape calendar with the function `cal-tex-cursor-month-landscape`.  I am using TexLive 2012 on a OSX.  The calendar image gets truncated on portrait orientation paper -- i.e., TexLive 2012 does not know to print the image in landscape.  How can I use `cal-tex-cursor-month-landscape` to properly generate a landscape calendar using TexLive 2012?

```latex
%   This buffer was produced by cal-tex.el.
%   To print a calendar, type
%       M-x tex-buffer RET
%       M-x tex-print  RET
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\hbadness 20000
\hfuzz=1000pt
\vbadness 20000
\lineskip 0pt
\marginparwidth 0pt
\oddsidemargin  -2cm
\evensidemargin -2cm
\marginparsep   0pt
\topmargin      0pt
\textwidth      7.5in
\textheight     9.5in
\newlength{\cellwidth}
\newlength{\cellheight}
\newlength{\boxwidth}
\newlength{\boxheight}
\newlength{\cellsize}
\newcommand{\myday}[1]{}
\newcommand{\caldate}[6]{}
\newcommand{\nocaldate}[6]{}
\newcommand{\calsmall}[6]{}
%
\special{landscape}% 
\textwidth 9.5in{}% 
\textheight 7in{}% 
% 
\def\holidaymult{.08}% 
\fboxsep=0pt
\long\def\caldate#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
    \fbox{\hbox to\cellwidth{%
     \vbox to\cellheight{%
       \hbox to\cellwidth{%
          {\hspace*{1mm}\Large \bf \strut #2}\hspace{.05\cellwidth}%
          \raisebox{\holidaymult\cellheight}%
                   {\parbox[t]{.75\cellwidth}{\tiny \raggedright #4}}}
       \hbox to\cellwidth{%
           \hspace*{1mm}\parbox{.95\cellwidth}{\tiny \raggedright #3}}
       \hspace*{1mm}%
       \hbox to\cellwidth{#6}%
       \vfill%
       \hbox to\cellwidth{\hfill \tiny #5 \hfill}%
       \vskip 1.4pt}%
     \hskip -0.4pt}}}
{}% 
\renewcommand{\myday}[1]%
{\makebox[\cellwidth]{\hfill\large\bf#1\hfill}}
%
{}% 
\begin{document}% 
\pagestyle{empty}% 
\setlength{\cellwidth}{24cm}% 
\setlength{\cellwidth}{0.157143\cellwidth}
\setlength{\cellheight}{18cm}% 
\setlength{\cellheight}{0.166667\cellheight}
\ \par{}% 
\vspace*{-3cm}% 
\def\calmonth#1#2%
{\begin{center}%
\Huge\bf\uppercase{#1} #2 \\[1cm]%
\end{center}}%
\vspace*{-1.5cm}%
%
{}% 
\def\lastmonth{\hbox to\cellwidth{%
\vbox to\cellheight{%
\vfil  \hbox to\cellwidth{%
\hfil\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{0mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{0mm}}}%
\multicolumn{7}{c}{March 2017}\\[1mm]
Su & Mo & Tu & We & Th & Fr & Sa\\[0.7mm]
 &  &  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\[0.5mm]
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11\\[0.5mm]
12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\[0.5mm]
19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25\\[0.5mm]
26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 
\end{tabular}\hfil}\vfil}}}%
\def\nextmonth{\hbox to\cellwidth{%
\vbox to\cellheight{%
\vfil  \hbox to\cellwidth{%
\hfil\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{0mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{1mm}}r@{\hspace{0mm}}}%
\multicolumn{7}{c}{May 2017}\\[1mm]
Su & Mo & Tu & We & Th & Fr & Sa\\[0.7mm]
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\[0.5mm]
7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13\\[0.5mm]
14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20\\[0.5mm]
21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27\\[0.5mm]
28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 
\end{tabular}\hfil}\vfil}}}%
\calmonth{April}{2017}
\vspace*{-0.5cm}% 
\myday{Sunday}%% 
\myday{Monday}%% 
\myday{Tuesday}%% 
\myday{Wednesday}%% 
\myday{Thursday}%% 
\myday{Friday}%% 
\myday{Saturday}%% 
\\[.2cm]% 
\lastmonth\nextmonth\hspace*{-2\cellwidth}\caldate{ }{ }{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{ }{ }{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{ }{ }{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{ }{ }{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{ }{ }{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{ }{ }{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{April}{1}{}{}{91/274}{}% 
\hfill\\% 
\caldate{April}{2}{}{}{92/273}{}% 
\caldate{April}{3}{}{}{93/272}{}% 
\caldate{April}{4}{}{}{94/271}{}% 
\caldate{April}{5}{}{}{95/270}{}% 
\caldate{April}{6}{}{}{96/269}{}% 
\caldate{April}{7}{}{}{97/268}{}% 
\caldate{April}{8}{}{}{98/267}{}% 
\hfill\\% 
\caldate{April}{9}{}{}{99/266}{}% 
\caldate{April}{10}{}{}{100/265}{}% 
\caldate{April}{11}{}{}{101/264}{}% 
\caldate{April}{12}{}{}{102/263}{}% 
\caldate{April}{13}{}{}{103/262}{}% 
\caldate{April}{14}{}{}{104/261}{}% 
\caldate{April}{15}{}{}{105/260}{}% 
\hfill\\% 
\caldate{April}{16}{}{}{106/259}{}% 
\caldate{April}{17}{}{}{107/258}{}% 
\caldate{April}{18}{}{}{108/257}{}% 
\caldate{April}{19}{}{}{109/256}{}% 
\caldate{April}{20}{}{}{110/255}{}% 
\caldate{April}{21}{}{}{111/254}{}% 
\caldate{April}{22}{}{}{112/253}{}% 
\hfill\\% 
\caldate{April}{23}{}{}{113/252}{}% 
\caldate{April}{24}{}{}{114/251}{}% 
\caldate{April}{25}{}{}{115/250}{}% 
\caldate{April}{26}{}{}{116/249}{}% 
\caldate{April}{27}{}{}{117/248}{}% 
\caldate{April}{28}{}{}{118/247}{}% 
\caldate{April}{29}{}{}{119/246}{}% 
\hfill\\% 
\caldate{April}{30}{}{}{120/245}{}% 
\caldate{}{}{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{}{}{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{}{}{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{}{}{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{}{}{}{}{}{}%
\caldate{}{}{}{}{}{}%
\end{document}%
```

Comment: The file should be processed with `latex` and `dvips` in order to get the desired result (I've just tried it and it works for me with TL2016).  Running `pdflatex` on it says `Non-PDF special ignored!` which is the relevant `\special{landscape}` line.  Are you using `pdflatex`?

Comment: You were faster, Arash :-)  Besides that, adding `landscape` to the document class options should also help.

Comment: @ArashEsbati -- yes, I'm using `pdflatex`, so that appears to be the problem.  @Jan -- I will try adding `landscape` to the document class later today and report back with the results (using `pdflatex`) -- thank you.

Comment: @Jan -- I had a chance to test substituting the document class `article` with `landscape`, but that prevents the PDF from being generated by `pdflatex`.  The following setting works:  `\usepackage[left=.2in,top=0.15in,papersize={8.5in,11.0in},landscape,twoside=false]{geometry}`.  I'll need to find the internal function responsible for generating the LaTeX code within Emacs and add that line, or take it one step further and put in a condition (if that is possible) for whether `latex` or `pdflatex` is used to compile (disregarding `\special{landscape}` if the latter condition exists.

Comment: @lawlist You should add `landscape` to the list of options of `article` class like this: `\documentclass[landscape]{article}`.

Comment: @Jan -- thank you -- I added a note to the answer that addresses your suggestion - greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Arash Esbati, the problem was indeed due to the fact that `pdflatex` does not support `\special{landscape}`  One solution is to replace the aforementioned code with a call to the `geometry` package that works with `pdflatex`.  I chose to hardcode a let-bound value for `cal-tex-preamble-extra` that takes effect if the LANDSCAPE argument is used.  I commented out `(cal-tex-cmd "\\special" "landscape")`.

@Jan has pointed out in one of the comments above that `landscape` can be added to the document class such that it would look like `\documentclass[landscape]{article}`.  The function `cal-tex-preamble` accepts one argument called `args`, but a look at the code reveals that it really only accepts one string that gets inserted into the square brackets.  Since the argument SIZE is already being used, it would be necessary to concatenate that with the proposed `landscape` option.  This would be a viable alternative to using the `geometry` package.

```lisp
(defun cal-tex-insert-preamble (weeks landscape size &optional append)
  "Initialize the output LaTeX calendar buffer, `cal-tex-buffer'.
Select the output buffer, and insert the preamble for a calendar
of WEEKS weeks.  Insert code for landscape mode if LANDSCAPE is
non-nil.  Use point-size SIZE.  Optional argument APPEND, if
non-nil, means add to end of buffer without erasing current contents."
  (let ((width "18cm")
        (height "24cm")
        (cal-tex-preamble-extra
          (when landscape
            (concat
              "\\usepackage"
              "[left=.25in,top=0.15in,papersize={8.5in,11.0in},"
              "landscape,twoside=false]{geometry}"))))
    (setq width "24cm"
          height "18cm")
    (unless append
      (cal-tex-preamble size)
      (if (not landscape)
          (progn
            (cal-tex-cmd "\\oddsidemargin -1.75cm")
            (cal-tex-cmd "\\def\\holidaymult" ".06"))
        ;; (cal-tex-cmd "\\special" "landscape")
        (cal-tex-cmd "\\textwidth 9.5in")
        (cal-tex-cmd "\\textheight 7in")
        (cal-tex-comment)
        (cal-tex-cmd "\\def\\holidaymult" ".08"))
      (cal-tex-cmd cal-tex-caldate)
      (cal-tex-cmd cal-tex-myday)
      (cal-tex-b-document)
      (cal-tex-cmd "\\pagestyle" "empty"))
    (cal-tex-cmd "\\setlength{\\cellwidth}" width)
    (insert (format "\\setlength{\\cellwidth}{%f\\cellwidth}\n"
                    (/ 1.1 (length cal-tex-which-days))))
    (cal-tex-cmd "\\setlength{\\cellheight}" height)
    (insert (format "\\setlength{\\cellheight}{%f\\cellheight}\n"
                    (/ 1.0 weeks)))
    (cal-tex-cmd "\\ \\par")
    (cal-tex-vspace "-3cm")))
```